# Remote login hangs on El Capitan

Tags: imac, ssh

I am trying to SSH my iMac from an Ubuntu server (without root access), but the command just hangs without ever connecting. I enabled the "Remote Login" from the iMac's settings, but here is what happens when I try to ssh from the server:

```
$ ssh -v mymac -l mylogin
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to mymac [129.67.12.95] port 22.
```

I am also confident it is not because of the server, because we tried from two different servers and a Mac laptop, same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed in your debug output is that you are attempting a connection to a public IP rather than an internal IP address.

This raises the question of where that IP address hits before it gets to your Mac. Almost certainly you have a router that is getting in the way.

Try making the connection to the Mac's internal address from another machine sitting inside your net. This is much more likely to work. Go to the "Network" preference pane in System Preferences and this will tell you what the network address of your Mac actually is.